# PlayStation 4 Pro, brand new, 3 beeps

Tags: ps4

I have just returned and replaced a PS4P that I believed was DOA after all it gave was 3 beeps.

I have set up the replacement and I am getting 3 beeps again.

Am I doing something wrong or have I been really unlucky?

I have tried.
- running directly from the plug socket (currently on a multitap but only the PS4P and the TV are running off it and the TV works fine.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you pressing the power button (left side) or eject button (right side)? I know pressing the eject button while there is no disk in the system will give 3 beeps

Comment: Ah.  I was pressing just next to the usb ports.  I feel dumb.  Why have the 3 beeps as an error message? And when the PS4 is off too! That makes it even easier to make a mistake, especially when there are no visible buttons on the front. Post that as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Did it not come with instructions/quick start guide? I would've assumed those could have cleared up your issue fairly quickly (or prevented it altogether). Assuming a new system is DOA without reading any of the documentation is pretty odd to me...

Comment: Possibly, probably.  It was literally: power to the unit, hdmi to the TV, control pad to usb. Look for on button. Nothing obvious. Feel along the front, depress, three beeps.  Generally the lack of fans and noise like stuff spinning up is cause for alarm so I went straight to Sony help page and typing three beeps into their search function takes you straight to the replacement page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Answer based on comments above*</sub>

Given that the system is brand new, you were likely pressing the eject button instead of the power button. If that is the case, then this is standard behavior for the PS4 Pro.

On the PS4 Pro, the eject button is located on the right of the system directly above the USB ports. The power button is located on the left side of the system. If there is no disc in the system, pressing the eject button will cause the system beep 3 times consecutively to indicate there is no disc to eject.